# Mysql checking . record for one day against record in different date 'Same-Store Sales'

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql

Same-Store Sales concept if where you check how store performing today against same store yesterday to show if revenue grow or decrease. 
so I have table with `5+ millions` of records structured like

```
store_id , stats_date, trans_cnt (number of transactions), 
revenue, time_period(week, day , year)
```

is there a way to avoid using `cursor`, to check if `store_id` record exist yesterday day and today and see if revenue goes up or down?

Comment: Sample data and desired results always help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved join on same filter data from table or sub table .

ie

```
 select tdate.store_id  ,(tdate.revenue - ydate.revenue) as diffrence 
 from (select store_id ,revenue from tablename where stats_date =getdata()) tdate 
   join ( select store_id ,revenue from tablename  where stats_date = DATEADD(day, -1,getdata()) )  as ydate
  on tdate.store_id = ydate.store_id
```

Note:

ydate  filter data for yesterday

tdate   filter data for yesterday

More filter condition can be added .

Or you are looking for

```
 select tdate.store_id  ,(tdate.revenue - ydate.revenue) as diffrence 
   from  tablename tdate 
   join tablename   as ydate
    on tdate.store_id = ydate.store_id
    and tdate.stats_date =ydate.DATEADD(day, -1,stats_date)
```

Comment: yes and now , because i have records for almost . 2 yers in table and wright . this conditions will be a nightmare, is there a way to check it dynamically, without using a cursor

Comment: Here we do not have any cursor and second it is dynamically as we are calculating  date dynamically  .  for performance  we can have two variable to sotre / dynamic value for today and yesterday.

Comment: I use your idea . but . still have to use cursor because your approach works only for two dates today and yesterday . but if i need to compare yesterday and day before this logic doesn't work :(